# Warning: Missing argument 1 for Personnage::__construct()

Tags: php, constructor

I am receiving following error for my code. Please help me out.

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Personnage::__construct(), called in
>   public_html/PooEnPhp/index.php on line 24 and defined in
>   public_html/PooEnPhp/Personnage.class.php on line 22

Class file : Personnage.class.php

```
<?php

class Personnage {

    private $_force =  20;
    private $_localisation = 'Lyon';
    private $_experience = 0;
    private $_degats = 0;



    // Create a connstructor with two arguments
    public function __construct($force, $degats) {
        echo 'Voici le constructeur ! '; 
        $this->_force = $force;
        $this->_degats = $degats;
    }
```

The file instantiating the Personnage class:  index.php

```
<?php

            function chargerClasse($classe) {
                require $classe . '.class.php'; 
            }

            //autoload the function chargerClasse
            spl_autoload_register('chargerClasse');

           // instantiate the Personnage class using the default constructor (the one implied without argument)
            $perso = new Personnage();
```

Normally in index.php I should be able to instanciate the the Personnage class using the implied default  constructor __construct().

But I am getting the error above. Can somebody explain me why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in here:

```
// Create a connstructor with two arguments
public function __construct($force, $degats) {
    echo 'Voici le constructeur ! '; 
    $this->_force = $force;
    $this->_degats = $degats;
}
```

The `$force` and `$degates` are both set as obligatory parameters.
To be able to call `new Personnage()` with setting any parameters you have to change your class to this:

```
<?php
class Personnage {

    private $_force =  20;
    private $_localisation = 'Lyon';
    private $_experience = 0;
    private $_degats = 0;

    // Create a connstructor with two arguments
    public function __construct($force = 20, $degats = 0) {
        echo 'Voici le constructeur ! '; 
        $this->_force = $force;
        $this->_degats = $degats;
    }
}
```

?>

This basically sets default values for the parameters so it will be ok not to supply them.

Comment: It works. After supplying default values to the constructor as you answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

because the constructor expect two arguments:

```
public function __construct($force, $degats) {
```

and you call it without any Argument:

```
$perso = new Personnage();
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a constructor that takes two arguments whch means you need to supply those args when instantiating it, e.g.:

```
$perso = new Personnage($force, $degats);
```